# Algorithmic Character Comparison Logic Failing

Tags: java, algorithm, output

I am working on a project where I have to find a missing word from a text file called script.txt and put it in another .txt file which contains the sentences that need the missing word.

I am storing all the sentences that need a missing word in an array list. I am able to find the missing word for the first and the second sentences but for some reason my code is unable to find the missing word for the remaining 4 other sentences.

I am using two pointers i an j. i is for the Script file and j is for Sentences file. When i is equal to the length of the Script file it means we have reached the end of the script and we were unable to find the word.

Here is the part of the code which compares the characters in both txt files, this part of code is in a function called KMP_Algorithm(String Current_Statement, String Movie_Script);

```
while(i < Length_of_the_Script)
        {
            if(Current_Statement.charAt(j) == The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(i))
            {
                i++; 
                j++; 

            }
            else if(Current_Statement.charAt(j) != The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(i) && Current_Statement.charAt(j) == Underscore)
            {
                j = lps[j - 1];
                //Replace the underscores with the word
                //System.out.println("There is a missing word at " + i); 
                Missing_Word = Get_Word(); 
                New_Current_Statement = Current_Statement.replaceAll("___", Missing_Word);
                System.out.println(New_Current_Statement); 
                break; 
            }
            else if(i < Length_of_the_Script && Current_Statement.charAt(j) != The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(i))
            {
                if(j != 0)
                {
                    j = lps[j - 1]; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    i = i + 1; 
                }
            }

        }

        //Everything looks great inside this if statement 
        if(i == Length_of_the_Script)
        {
            System.out.println("WORD NOT FOUND"); 
        }
    }
```

Here is the function which gets the word from the Script file :-

```
static String Get_Word()
    {
        int Word_Pointer = i;
        int Missing_Character = 0; 
        String Missing_W; 
         char Missing_Word_Characters[] = new char[10]; 
        while(The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(Word_Pointer) != WhiteSpace)
        {
            //get the character and increment Word_Pointer
            Missing_Word_Characters[Missing_Character] = The_Truman_Show_Script.charAt(Word_Pointer); 
            Missing_Character++;
            Word_Pointer++;     
        }


            Missing_W = new String(Missing_Word_Characters); 
            return Missing_W; 

    }
```

Here is the for loop which selects the Statements and called the algorithm function :-

```
for(int q = 0; q < Statements_List.size(); q++)
        {
            Current_Statement = Statements_List.get(q); 
            System.out.println(Current_Statement); 
            KMP_Algorithm(Current_Statement, The_Truman_Show_Script); 
            System.out.println(); 
        }
```

It isn't supposed to show "WORD NOT FOUND" for the remaining sentences

Your help would be much appreciated. 
Thank You

Comment: That looks very much like a creepy mix of Java and C concepts... That aside, did you try finding your error with a debugger?

Comment: I am very new to Java, I am not sure how to use a debugger

Comment: Debugging does not necessarily mean to use a debugger. You can also debug old-school style with a lot of outputs to the console `System.err.println(...)` to check what happens, which values are in your variables ...